# Access oracle application express from macs on the same network

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have just started learning databases and oracle from scratch and want a way to access the software from my macbook.I have installed oracle xe 11gr2 on my home windows pc.  I am an absolute beginner and don't want to use sophisticated clients like SQLDeveloper or commandline but I have got quite familiar with Oracle Application Express for my learning purposes.
How to configure my pc so that I can connect to the installed database and access application express from my macbook or another device on the same network? 
Although there is an option like using virtualmachine and portforwarding in virtualbox but that isn't feasible since I am low on storage space on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

You must connect to the http server running on your PC with a browser. This implies that your PC must be on a network accessible from your macbook

If you selected to use the embedded PL/SQL gateway and you can connect to APEX like such;

http://localhost:8080/apex
or 
http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin

Use the URL above and replace 'localhost' with the IP address of your PC

You can get further information from the Oracle Application Express Administration Guide/Logging in to Oracle Application Express Administration Services

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12512/adm_login.htm#AEADM168